# Error adding an index to a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexed-view

I have created a view using the following code

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.two_weeks_performance WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
  SELECT dbo.day_dim.date_time AS Date, 
         dbo.order_dim.quantity AS Target_Acheived
    FROM dbo.day_dim 
    JOIN dbo.order_fact ON dbo.day_dim.day_id = dbo.order_fact.day_id 
    JOIN dbo.branch_dim ON dbo.order_fact.branch_id = dbo.branch_dim.branch_id 
    JOIN dbo.order_dim ON dbo.order_fact.order_id = dbo.order_dim.order_id   
GROUP BY dbo.order_dim.quantity, dbo.day_dim.date_time`
```

Now when I use:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX two_weeks_performance_I ON two_weeks_performance (Date)
```

I am getting an error:

> Cannot create index because its select list does not use the correct usage of COUNT_BIG(). Consider adding COUNT_BIG(*) to the select.

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what you have to do - add COUNT_BIG(*) to your select list.

From [Creating Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx):

> If GROUP BY is specified, the view
>   select list must contain a
>   COUNT_BIG(*) expression, and the view
>   definition cannot specify HAVING,
>   ROLLUP, CUBE, or GROUPING SETS.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.two_weeks_performance WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
  SELECT dbo.day_dim.date_time AS Date, 
         dbo.order_dim.quantity AS Target_Acheived,
         COUNT_BIG(*) as Cnt 
    FROM dbo.day_dim 
    JOIN dbo.order_fact ON dbo.day_dim.day_id = dbo.order_fact.day_id 
    JOIN dbo.branch_dim ON dbo.order_fact.branch_id = dbo.branch_dim.branch_id 
    JOIN dbo.order_dim ON dbo.order_fact.order_id = dbo.order_dim.order_id   
GROUP BY dbo.order_dim.quantity, dbo.day_dim.date_time
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX two_weeks_performance_I ON two_weeks_performance (Date)
```